matlab rref with symbolic matrix
How can I find the row reduced form of a symbolic matrix with matlab. I have the symbolic toolkit installed and looking at the documentation it says to just use the rref function like normal. However, this doesn't seem to work properly.
Example
syms h
M = [
1 h
2 3]
rref(M)

This results in
[1, 0]
[0, 1]

However I would expect the answer to be closer too
[1, h]
[0, 3-2*h]

How do I do this? Other operations (add, subtract, det) work fine with symbolic matrices. Is there a different command to use? Or is this just not possible?
Thanks

I think the output produced by Matlab is correct. Note that using the numerical version of rref (with some number instead of h) gives the same result. From Wikipedia: (a) the leading entry in each nonzero row must be 1; and (b) each column containing a leading 1 must have 0 in all its other entries. According to (a), the leading entry of the second row must be 1, not 3-2*h. Also, from (b), entry (1,2) must be 0, not h as you expected

@LuisMendo You are right, that is my bad
